# why is input from my form not writting to the sqlite3 database in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite

I would like to update my list after adding some inputs through a form but i cannot see my updated list. I see the existing items in my list ,but when i add a new item it does not appear on the list. I can manually add it using the admin pannel and view it in the list(a whole different path),but not with the form i created to take input and update the list. I was able to query my database and input from the form is not getting written to the database, that's why its not displaying any changes.Below is my code

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    notes = models.CharField(max_length = 1000000000000000000000000000)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.notes
```

form.py

```
from blog.models import BlogPost

class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['notes', 'done',]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect,HttpRequest
from blog.models import BlogPost
from blog.form import BlogForm


def home(request):
    context = {
            'welcome_text': 'Welcome to the home page. View some more stuff soon'
            }
    return render(request,'home.html', context)

def blogpost(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BlogForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if  form.save():
                message.success(request, "the task was added")


        return redirect('blogpost')
    else:

        all_blogs = BlogPost.objects.all

        return render(request, 'blog.html',{'the_blogs': all_blogs } )
```

blog.html

```
{%extends 'base.html' %}


{% block title%}
        <title> Blog  </title>
{% endblock title%}

{%block content %}
        <div class="container">
         <br>
         {%for message in messages%}
                {{message}}
         {% endfor %}
         <form method = 'POST'>
                {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name = 'blog'  placeholder = 'new blog' >
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Blog</button>
        </form>
        <br>
                <table class="table table-hover table-dark">

                        <thead>
                                <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Blog </th>
                                        <th scope="col">Done</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Date</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {% for item in the_blogs %}
                                {% if item.done %}
                                        <tr class="table-success">
                                                <td >{{item.notes}}</td>
                                                <td >Not-Completed</td>
                                                <td>{{item.date}}</td>
                                                <td>edit</td>
                                                <td>delete</td>
                                        </tr>
                                {% endif %}

                        {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
{%endblock content%}
```

if you need more information regarding this, here is a link to my GitHub repository with more code.
**https://github.com/wfidelis/Django-App**

Comment: Just a side note; you can use `models.TextField()` instead of `models.CharField(max_length = 1000000000000000000000000000)`, which looks quite scary.

Comment: Object is not being added when you are using form or object is added but not shown?

Comment: haha okay Thank you @TedKleinBergman, I will change that.

Comment: @HeisAif its not being added. I querried the database and saw that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to correct the code indentation and the get call part, pass the form to context object and call it with double curly brackets on templates, also add an action attribute to the template.

```
def blogpost(request):
    all_blogs = BlogPost.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BlogForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if  form.save():
                message.success(request, "the task was added")
        return redirect('blogpost')
    else:
        form = BlogForm()
    return render(request, 'blog.html',{'form': form, 'the_blogs': all_blogs } )


<form method='POST' action="">{% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.as_p }}
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Blog</button>
<form/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add a blog, don't redirect, try rendering the page with the new list the same as how you did it here:

```
  all_blogs = BlogPost.objects.all
  return render(request, 'blog.html',{'the_blogs': all_blogs } )
```

or try returning new object created as JSON format to the front-end (as a response of the POST request) and front-end will add it to the HTML with jQuery or JS